# Spring best practices for multi application using part of persistence layer

Tags: spring

I'm developing 2 new applications (backend - CRM & frontend - Portal) with Maven / Spring / Hibernate / PostgreSQL.

Portal app (maven module) needs to use some entities from persistence layer through CRM application.

How I can achieve this?

- Does CRM module have a  Portal dependency? - I don't think this is a  good solution. If I change some data in CRM app, I can't control cache eviction in Portal app.
- DO entities from CRM's persitence layer fetch from Portal via WS/REST?
- Is there another solution?

Example:

```
public interface PoiService {

    // Poi is entity of persistence layer of CRM's application.
    List<Poi> getPois(double latitude, double longtitude, double distance);

}
```

There is more entities that are shared (only from CRM to Portal app).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Comment: Create a separate project to package the entities in another jar

Comment: @Leon But this not solve my problem, because I have 2 persistence units, one for Portal and one for CRM. How I can evict cache in portal if I change some entities in CRM?

Comment: Don't cache in 2 places. If I understand correctly portal is just an interface to crm. Crm should be the only one caching.

Comment: @Leon No, portal is war and crm is second war. And PoiService I need use in Portal and in CRM too and Poi is "shared" entity. I'm sorry for "poor verbal skills" :/ thanks

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand better now. The two applications should not have access to the same database. If crm needs data from portal, then portal must make the data available via an api and only portal should cache that data.

Comment: And what about use separate project with shared entities & DAOs and use "shared" cache in both persistence units?